# trouble shooting the connection between systems by using telnet?

Tags: linux, telnet, loopback, windows-server-2003

I have a windowsystem called "A" and Linux system called"B" .Our application software is client -server software. So in this scenario server part of application is resding in a window system and client part is in linux system.Server is getting some logs through telent connection where telent server is in Linux system and client in in window system.
Now come to the problem , i feel it is bit strange.Whats going on is telnet connection between these two systems goes off once or twice in a day, but will establish after one hour. I was searching the reason behind this strange behaviour. I am sure there is no firewall between systems by doing netstat and can see that connection establishes , so probably port also opened(i guess) .
Then what will be the reason? as i explained earlier our application server part is a window system and has telnet client, its host file added an entry 127.0.0.1       localhost so with loopback address.So will that make any issues???
or  the second reason i am guessing is the listening port is actually open and actively being used, but its backlog of queued inbound connection requeusts has reached its maximum so there is no room available for the inbound connection request to be queued at that moment. Does this make any issue? if so what is remedy?
If any body has any reason behind this starnge behaviour post here

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2003:

reset ip settings!

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

Disable IPv6:

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 6to4 set state state=disabled undoonstop=disabled
netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state state=disabled
```

see rule:

```
netsh firewall show portopening
netsh firewall show allowedprogram
netsh interface portproxy dump
```

see connection:

```
netstat -aton | findstr /V /L "*:*" | more
```

The IRPStackSize parameter specifies the number of stack locations in I/O request packets (IRPs)

[IRPStackSize](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285089/en-us)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
IRPStackSize    50(Dec) DWORD
```

Comment: will that work? because only certain periods telnet loose connection, rest all time it is working fine.So i would wonder whether it is due to firewall or port problem??your suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: @vettori I find it difficult to make assumptions for you. I suggested ways to solve problems that you have described. Increasing the length of the stack will help with the elimination of problems with a queue of packets. Disabling IPv6 and reset can also eliminate some common problems. It is necessary to make the experience and wait).

Comment: that is great , i am concentrating on IRPStacksize, so probably due to the backlog of queued inbound connection requeusts may be the problem

Comment: @vettori see to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948496/en and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912222/en and search `disable windows server 2003 scalable networking pack` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463253.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463471.aspx nic driver error problem. Search ndis 6.0 network driver.

Comment: Fighting W2K2 SP2 reminds me of this ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4Jo9grHynLA#t=839s

Comment: one more question , i am going to s reset ip settings, do i need to do any additional changes or need to configure anything. I will increase IRPstacksize also

Comment: @vettori `netsh dump > .\nicdump.txt` - save nic config, `netsh exec .\nicdump.txt` - restore nic config, `ipconfig /all > .\ipconfig-all.txt` - save ip config to text. Set settings and reboot. Need restart and if server W2K3 remote setup and autorization DHCP. And write script restore/reboot station if it remote).